# UIScrollView inside of UITableView messing up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollViews inside of cells of a UITableView.  Everything is working as expected except... when I scroll a cell off the table view and then scroll it back, the UIScrollView  that is now visible inside the cell, appears to have it's contentOffset shifted by half the width of the scroll view.  But when I look at the contentOffset value, it is correct and has not been shifted.  At this point, any adjustments to the contentOffset now have this shifted valued added to it. I'm stumped, does anyone have an idea how the images are getting shifting inside the UIScrollView? Or how i can fix this?

Also worth noting, I am using autoLayout and constraints to automatically set up the contentSize of the scrollView.  That appears to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out autoLayout was my problem.  For now I have turned off autoLayout for this view and directly set conentSize for the scrollView and the shifting bug goes away.  Likely I am incorrectly setting up my constraints.  Ideally I would have this working with autoLayout but for now I am going to have to leave it and possibly come back to it down the road.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a tableview. The scrolling did not work after I added rows; the bottom rows were not able to be scrolled to afterward. I had been calling setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO on the tableView, but after removing that line, everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the contentSize i also had the same issue before.
setTranslatesAutoresizing line should be deleted if you have added it